# Вопрос про вычет времени

Tags: php

Как написать условие если время1 - время2 > 30 минут делай то-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $interval = intval(strtotime($end) - strtotime($start));

    if ($interval > 1800) {
      // больше
    } else {
      // меньше
    }
```

Start и End - datetime (Y-m-d H:i:s)

Comment: `abs` не хорошо, если `time1` меньше `time2` то будет отрицательное число, а при abs будет положительно, и возможно сработает условия, хотя этого не должно быть

Comment: тогда лучше всего `$end - $start`, тогда отрицательного точно не будет

Comment: `$end - $start` да, но без `abs`, что бы условие не сработало если `$end` будет меньше `$start`

Comment: исправил в связи с вашими замечаниями

Comment: Благодарю всех!

Comment: Появилась Проблема. Я не могу использовать Y-m-d H:i:s в названии файлов.

Comment: А при чём тут файлы собственно?) в Вашем вопросе об этом нет ни слова

Comment: в базе тип поля даты поменял на TIMESTAMP все заработало. Да мне нужно выводить сообщение каждые 15 минут чтобы клиент делал рез. копию. Так и при создании рез. копии нужно указывать время

Answer (score 0):

Перевести всё дату в скажем `timestamp`, 30 минут в секунды и дальше проверять

```
if( ($time1 - $time2) > $secondTime) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - привести время в секунды, например через [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php)

```
$time1 = strtotime('10.07.2017 14:00');
$time2 = strtotime('10.07.2017 14:31');

$period = '1800' // 30 минут в секундах

if ($time1 -$time2 > $period) {
    //код который необохдимо выполнить
}
```